# Android SQLITE How to skip the row and display latest Result

Tags: android, sqlite, skip

In My System got a LOW STOCK page which will display the ITEM that's currently LOW STOCK.
The page will only display when LOWSTOCK when "THE MOMENT" was low stocks. 
Means, if there's a latest update of the PROCODE and the PROCODE not in LOW STOCK MOMENT. The page will DISPLAY NOTHING for the moment. 
I have a SIMPLE DATABASE AS FOLLOW

```
id || PROCODE ||  CURRENTAMOUNT || LOWALERTAMOUNT || STOCKINAMT || STOCKOUTAMT ||
01 || ITEM01  ||  1000          || 100            || -          || -
02 || ITEM01  ||  900           || 100            || -          || 100
03 || ITEM01  ||  90            || 100            || -          || 810
04 || ITEM01  ||  120           || 100            || 30         || -
```

In My **DatabaseAadapter.class.** The Code I use to retrieve the SQL is as followed:

```
public Cursor getAllLowUnitProducts(){

        return DB.query(DATABASE_PRO_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_PRO_CODE, KEY_NAME, CURRENTAMOUNT, LOWALERTAMOUNT, KEY_RACK}, LOWALERTAMOUNT  + " > " + CURRENTAMOUNT, null, KEY_PRO_CODE, null, KEY_ROWID, null);

    }
```

in the LowStock Class is as followed:

```
public void fillData() {

    Cursor remindersCursor = DBAdap.getAllLowUnitProducts();
    startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_PRO_CODE, DBAdapter.KEY_NAME, DBAdapter.CURRENTAMOUNT, DBAdapter.LOWALERTAMOUNT, DBAdapter.KEY_RACK};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.low_text01, R.id.low_text02, R.id.low_text03, R.id.low_text04, R.id.low_text05};      

    SimpleCursorAdapter SCA =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.low_stock_layout_row, remindersCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(SCA);}
```

Now in my "LOW STOCK PAGE". I should not show the "03" record in the ID due to the ITEM01 has a higher CURRENTAMOUNT than LOWALERTAMOUNT. But in my LOWSTOCKPAGE. It still display. Is there anyway not to display it? 
(MY LOWSTOCKPAGE should DISPLAY NOTHING due to have the 04 ID)

Anyway to do in SQL Way ?

Comment: `where currentamount <= lowalertamount`?

Comment: `the ITEM01 has a higher CURRENTAMOUNT than LOWALERTAMOUNT` you have 4 different ITEM01 with 4 different values. if you want to select only the latest, you need to select the max id

Comment: @MarcB Hi. Code Updated.

Comment: @njzk2 Hi Yes. You are right. Now In my results. The results should display nothing (due to availability of [_id 04]). Means my results should display EMPTY/NOTHING while comparing Between the LOWALERTAMOUNT with the CURRENTAMOUNT of the ITEM01.